# How to tell if VCR completed the cassette

Tags: ruby, vcr

How can I tell if VCR has consumed all the recorded data? If the tested program terminates the API accesses or does none at all, the VCR test still completes normally (the test checks for no error raised and a completion message at the end). There are a variety of ways to check state, but having the tested app successfully consume the cassette indicates a lot more than any state artifact I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the source code for `insert_cassette` options:

@option options :allow_unused_http_interactions [Boolean] If set to
false, an error will be raised if a cassette is ejected before all
previously recorded HTTP interactions have been used.
Defaults to true. Note that when an error has already occurred
(as indicated by the `$!` variable) unused interactions will be
allowed so that we don't silence the original error (which is almost
certainly more interesting/important).

and interacts with this `eject_cassette` option:

@option options :skip_no_unused_interactions_assertion [Boolean]
If `true` is given, this will skip the "no unused HTTP interactions"
assertion enabled by the `:allow_unused_http_interactions => false`
cassette option. This is intended for use when your test has had
an error, but your test framework has already handled it.

So this gets used as:

```
it 'successfully accesses the proper APIs' do
  VCR.use_cassette('/some/path', allow_unused_http_interactions: false) do
    expect do
      expect do
        described_class.new(param1, param2).process
      end.to_not raise_exception
    end.to output(/Done!/).to_stdout
  end
end
```